# Convert Python dict key and value to one String?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I've got a dictionary with values like

```
{
'Name': 'Clinton',
'Car': 'Ford'
}
```

and I want them to be a pair String of key and value, so that the result when I print it, should look like:

```
Name: Clinton
Car: Ford
```

Comment: where is your code and where is the problem? you should read key, value and join those strings

Comment: you can use : `print('\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in d.items()))`

Comment: really? still not deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Most of Python's native objects have built-in **str** and **repr** methods. This means that print(dictname) will work seamlessly, as it calls str(dictname) behind the scenes.

If you need or want to customize the print you can iterate the dict with a for loop like this:

```
for key in dictname:
   print("%s: %s" % (key, dictname[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the dictionary's key, value pair as a string in a list. Something like following:

```
dict_list = []

for key, value in given_dict.items():
    temp_string = str(key) + ": " + str(value)
    dict_list.append(temp_string)

#and for printing
print(*dict_list, sep='\n')
```